# How to utilize Raspberry PI in daily life task?

Tags: home-automation

Folks i am new to Raspberry PI. I have read brief about from wiki link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi and also heard about it from my friend about its potential power which we can use in our daily life.  To start with it, Could somebody guide me how i can optimize/automate one of any common man daily life task with raspberry pi. I am really excited about it and want to utilize it in my daily life somehow to start with.

Any pointers would be great help>

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately this question doesn't fit the site format. If you want general chit-chat about the Raspberry Pi please join us in [chat].

Answer (score 4):

A common problem :-)

Try Googleing for 'Raspberry Pi projects' to see what others have done.

Here's a good place to start - [Make Magazine's 47 Inspirational projects](http://blog.makezine.com/2013/04/14/47-raspberry-pi-projects-to-inspire-your-next-build/)

Answer (score 3):

Find a problem in your life that needs solved, and then solve it :)  Want to know when you lights are on or off in the house?  Measure and log temperature in your home?  How about your own IP enabled weather station?  Start you coffee pot when your alarm clock goes off?

You name it, you can do it with the Pi!

Mostly, just have fun with it!